# Javascript Rails template doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I try to make an Ajax-based solution for web-store.
So I have the Cart, and when user adds something, I want not to have all page reloaded, but only "Cart" template.
(Line Item belongs to Cart)
Create method in Line Item:

```
#usualstuff
respond_to do |format|
if @line_item.save
format.html { redirect_to(store_url) }
format.js
format.xml { render :xml => @line_item,
:status => :created, :location => @line_item }
else
...
```

Put the create.js file in /views/line_items

So here is the problem.

Actually it works. But when I click the button "Add to Cart", nothing changes, untill I reload page.

On server log is shown:

```
Rendered line_items/create.js (0.0ms)
```

0.0ms -for sure means something is wrong, but I can't figuare this out. Looks like rails just opens it and does nothing.

What may be the reason?

Code in create.js

```
page.replace_html('cart' , render(@cart))
```

Comment: would it be possible to see the ajax call you are making along with the success function?

Comment: i am quite nooby, so not sure that I got right you want to see

Comment: <%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path(:product_id => product),
:remote => true %>

Comment: the ajax call your making to update the cart dynamically

Comment: From the book about Rails: We want to change this to send an Ajax request instead. To do this, we simply
add a :remote => true parameter to the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So .js/.rjs template doesn't work in rails >3.0, should be .js.erb

Answer (score 0):

you still need to write the actual ajax request in javascript or jquery to call the method on the controller to update the display.

ruby is a server side language and so you need to make an ajax call to the server to get the data you wish to use to update your page.

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048702/rails-link-to-remote-from-within-ajax-loaded-content?rq=1) out they seem to be doing something similar to what you are it may be of some use. if your unsure on what ajax is have a look at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post).

hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: actually the trouble was that i used tutorial for previous version of Rails, before they forced jq instead of usuall js